Problem getting agents to move along paths in a network
I am working on a NetLogo model that simulates an evacuation scenario. The model is inspired by https://github.com/armostafizi/EvacuationModel/tree/master and includes pedestrians, cars, and intersections, with agents needing to move towards shelters. I have implemented a pathfinding algorithm (A*) to assign paths to the agents, but they are not moving when the 'go' procedure is called. I suspect that the paths might not be correctly assigned or there might be an issue in the movement logic.
When I try to run the second load procedure, I can see that no routes are being calculated (snippet of relevant part of printed output):
Route from: 15.853716036666523, 41.623823638016425 to 32.18922669275568, 40.520912445802615 path: []
Route from: 15.163137919357691, -67.82084096466812 to 22.54396556989329, -66.64832835878673 path: []
Route from: -36.23777333613987, 3.400348968081665 to -33.16409060116838, 6.658959146061804 path: []
Route from: 0.6749292737231305, 80.28529561529953 to -0.291584649119941, 73.70827305774586 path: []
Route from: -1.3740495834266073, 94.50788136012001 to 15.07829373781371, 83.58604416768537 path: []
Route from: 7.758160096647676, -59.32445556805049 to 1.4268799596547799, -60.473081987876974 path: []
Route from: 23.59462935062878, -24.566413426958054 to 19.440252192958454, -24.632454779700215 path: []
Route from: -12.68784769895467, 24.36163234283424 to -21.25725558520498, 23.200141062005827 path: []
Route from: -13.432629822336198, -15.442390249604951 to -14.616377283352566, -18.37497639871379 path: []
Route from: 4.03343774311876, 57.17331485629869 to 2.3488494672843743, 53.233401696574624 path: []
READ (2/2) DONE!

Here is the entire NetLogo code:
extensions [gis]

breed [residents resident]
breed [pedestrians pedestrian]
breed [cars car]
breed [intersections intersection]
directed-link-breed [roads road]

residents-own [init_dest reached? current_int moving? evacuated? dead? speed decision miltime path]
roads-own [crowd traffic mid-x mid-y]
intersections-own [shelter? id previous fscore gscore path evacuee_count myneighbors entrance? test]
pedestrians-own [current_int shelter next_int moving? evacuated? dead? speed path decision]
cars-own [current_int moving? evacuated? dead? next_int shelter speed path decision car_ahead space_hw speed_diff acc road_on]
globals [ev_times mouse-was-down? road-network shelter_locations shelter-locations evacuation-radius mortality_rate simulation_start_time patch_to_meter patch_to_feet fd_to_ftps fd_to_mph tick_to_sec min_lon min_lat max_evacuation_time]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;; HELPER FUNCTIONS ;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to-report mouse-clicked?
  report (mouse-was-down? = true and not mouse-down?)
end

to-report find-origins
  let origins no-turtles
  ask residents [
    let nearest-int min-one-of intersections [distance myself]
    set origins (turtle-set origins nearest-int)
  ]
  report origins
end

to-report rayleigh-random [sigma]
  report (sqrt((- ln(1 - random-float 1 ))*(2 *(sigma ^ 2))))
end

to make-decision
  let rnd random-float 100
  ifelse (rnd < 50) [ ; assuming 50% on foot and 50% by car
    set decision 1
    set miltime ((rayleigh-random Rsig1) + Rtau1 ) * 60 / tick_to_sec
  ] [
    set decision 2
    set miltime ((rayleigh-random Rsig2) + Rtau2 ) * 60 / tick_to_sec
  ]
end

to-report Astar [ source gl gls ]
  let rchd? false
  let dstn nobody
  let closedset []
  let openset []

  ask intersections [ set previous -1 set gscore 1000000 set fscore 1000000 ]
  set openset lput [who] of source openset

  ask source [
    set gscore 0
    set fscore (gscore + distance gl)
  ]

  while [ not empty? openset and (not rchd?) ] [
    let current Astar-smallest openset
    if member? current [who] of gls [
      set dstn turtle current
      set rchd? true
    ]
    set openset remove current openset
    set closedset lput current closedset

    ask turtle current [
      ask out-road-neighbors [
        let neighbor-who [who] of self
        let tent-gscore [gscore] of myself + [link-length] of (road [who] of myself who)
        let tent-fscore tent-gscore + distance gl
        if ( member? neighbor-who closedset and ( tent-fscore >= [fscore] of turtle neighbor-who ) ) [ stop ]
        if ( not member? neighbor-who closedset or ( tent-fscore < [fscore] of turtle neighbor-who )) [
          ask turtle neighbor-who [
            set previous current
            set gscore tent-gscore
            set fscore tent-fscore
            if not member? who openset [
              set openset lput who openset
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  let route []
  ifelse dstn != nobody [
    while [ [previous] of dstn != -1 ] [
      set route fput [who] of dstn route
      set dstn turtle ([previous] of dstn)
    ]
  ]
  [
    set route []
  ]
  report route
end

to-report Astar-smallest [ who_list ]
  let min-who 0
  let min-fscr 100000000
  foreach who_list [ [?1] ->
    let fscr [fscore] of intersection ?1
    if fscr < min-fscr [
      set min-fscr fscr
      set min-who ?1
    ]
  ]
  report min-who
end

to move-gm
  set car_ahead cars in-cone (150 / patch_to_feet) 20
  set car_ahead car_ahead with [self != myself]
  set car_ahead car_ahead with [not evacuated?]
  set car_ahead car_ahead with [moving?]
  set car_ahead car_ahead with [abs(subtract-headings heading [heading] of myself) < 160]
  set car_ahead car_ahead with [distance myself > 0.0001]
  set car_ahead min-one-of car_ahead [distance myself]
  ifelse is-turtle? car_ahead [
    set space_hw distance car_ahead
    set speed_diff [speed] of car_ahead - speed
    ifelse space_hw < (6 / patch_to_feet) [set speed 0]
    [
      set acc (alpha / fd_to_mph * 5280 / patch_to_feet) * ((speed) ^ 0) / ((space_hw) ^ 2) * speed_diff
      set speed speed + acc
    ]
    if speed > (space_hw - (6 / patch_to_feet)) [set speed min list (space_hw - (6 / patch_to_feet)) [speed] of car_ahead]
    if speed > (max_speed / fd_to_mph) [set speed (max_speed / fd_to_mph)]
    if speed < 0 [set speed 0]
  ]
  [
    if speed < (max_speed / fd_to_mph) [set speed speed + (acceleration / fd_to_ftps * tick_to_sec)]
    if speed > max_speed / fd_to_mph [set speed max_speed / fd_to_mph]
  ]
  if speed > distance next_int [set speed distance next_int]
end

to mark-evacuated
  if not evacuated? [
    set color green
    set moving? false
    set evacuated? true
    set dead? false
    set ev_times lput (ticks * tick_to_sec / 60) ev_times
    ask current_int [set evacuee_count evacuee_count + 1]
  ]
end

to mark-dead
  set color red
  set moving? false
  set evacuated? false
  set dead? true
end

to-report is-heading-right? [link_heading direction]
  if direction = "north" [ if abs(subtract-headings 0 link-heading) <= 90 [report true]]
  if direction = "east" [ if abs(subtract-headings 90 link-heading) <= 90 [report true]]
  if direction = "south" [ if abs(subtract-headings 180 link-heading) <= 90 [report true]]
  if direction = "west" [ if abs(subtract-headings 270 link-heading) <= 90 [report true]]
  report false
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;; SETUP INITIAL PARAMETERS ;:;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup-init-val
  set immediate_evacuation false
  set Ped_Speed 4
  set Ped_Sigma 0.65
  set max_speed 35
  set acceleration 5
  set deceleration 25
  set alpha 0.14
  set Rtau1 10
  set Rtau2 10
  set Rsig1 1.65
  set Rsig2 1.65
  set patch_to_meter 1
  set fd_to_ftps 0.3048
  set tick_to_sec 1
  set evacuation-radius 2 / patch_to_meter
  set max_evacuation_time 30
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;; READ GIS FILES ;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to read-gis-files
  gis:load-coordinate-system "new_part_of_aarhus/cut_aarhus_split.prj"
  set shelter_locations gis:load-dataset "shelters_reprojected/shelters_reprojected.shp"
  set road-network gis:load-dataset "new_part_of_aarhus/cut_aarhus_split.shp"

  let min-x 571124.0821833728
  let max-x 577657.318834567
  let min-y 6219999.98388973
  let max-y 6227772.827541529

  let expansion-margin 10
  set min-x min-x - expansion-margin
  set max-x max-x + expansion-margin
  set min-y min-y - expansion-margin
  set max-y max-y + expansion-margin

  let netlogo-envelope (list min-x max-x min-y max-y)
  gis:set-world-envelope netlogo-envelope

  print (word "World Envelope: " gis:world-envelope)
  print (word "NetLogo Envelope: " netlogo-envelope)
  print (word "Transformation Set")
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;; LOAD NETWORK ;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load-network
  ask intersections [ die ]
  ask roads [ die ]

  foreach gis:feature-list-of road-network [ i ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of i [ j ->
      let previous-node-pt nobody
      foreach j [ k ->
        let location gis:location-of k
        if not empty? location [
          let new-node-pt nobody
          create-intersections 1 [
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set myneighbors n-of 0 turtles
            set shelter? false
            set size 0.2
            set shape "circle"
            set color brown
            set hidden? true
            set new-node-pt self
          ]
          ifelse previous-node-pt = nobody [
            set previous-node-pt new-node-pt
          ] [
            ask previous-node-pt [ create-link-with new-node-pt ]
            set previous-node-pt new-node-pt
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ask intersections [ set myneighbors link-neighbors ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;; LOAD SHELTERS ;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load-shelters
  set shelter-locations []
  foreach gis:feature-list-of shelter_locations [ i ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of i [ j ->
      foreach j [ k ->
        let location gis:location-of k
        if not empty? location [
          let x item 0 location
          let y item 1 location
          set shelter-locations lput (list x y) shelter-locations
          create-intersections 1 [
            set xcor x
            set ycor y
            set shelter? true
            set shape "circle"
            set size 2
            set color yellow
          ]
          ; Debug print
          print (word "Shelter created at: " x ", " y)
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end


to-report check-evacuation
  let close-enough? false
  foreach shelter-locations [ shelter-coord ->
    let shelter-x item 0 shelter-coord
    let shelter-y item 1 shelter-coord
    if distancexy shelter-x shelter-y < evacuation-radius [
      set close-enough? true
    ]
  ]
  report close-enough?
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;; CONNECT SHELTERS ;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to connect-shelters
  foreach shelter-locations [ shelter-coord ->
    let shelter-x item 0 shelter-coord
    let shelter-y item 1 shelter-coord
    let nearest-int min-one-of intersections [distancexy shelter-x shelter-y]
    create-roads-between shelter-x shelter-y nearest-int
  ]
end

to create-roads-between [ shelter-x shelter-y nearest-int ]
  let shelter-int one-of intersections with [xcor = shelter-x and ycor = shelter-y]
  if (shelter-int != nobody and shelter-int != nearest-int) [
    ask nearest-int [
      create-road-to shelter-int
      ask shelter-int [ create-road-to myself ]
    ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;; LOAD POPULATION ;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load-population
  ask residents [ die ]
  ask pedestrians [ die ]
  ask cars [ die ]

  let min-xcor min [min-pxcor] of patches
  let max-xcor max [max-pxcor] of patches
  let min-ycor min [min-pycor] of patches
  let max-ycor max [max-pycor] of patches

  let num-residents 300

  repeat num-residents [
    let valid-location? false
    let x 0
    let y 0

    while [not valid-location?] [
      ifelse random 2 = 0 [
        let spawn-location one-of intersections
        if spawn-location != nobody [
          set x [xcor] of spawn-location
          set y [ycor] of spawn-location
          set valid-location? true
        ]
      ] [
        let selected-road one-of roads
        if selected-road != nobody [
          set x [mid-x] of selected-road
          set y [mid-y] of selected-road
          set valid-location? true
        ]
      ]
    ]

    create-residents 1 [
      set xcor x
      set ycor y
      set color orange
      set shape "dot"
      set size 2
      set moving? false
      set init_dest min-one-of intersections [distance myself]
      set speed random-normal Ped_Speed Ped_Sigma
      if fd_to_ftps != 0 [
        set speed speed / fd_to_ftps
      ]
      if speed < 0.001 [set speed 0.001]
      set evacuated? false
      set dead? false
      set reached? false
      set path []
      make-decision
      if immediate_evacuation [
        set miltime 0
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;; LOAD ROUTES ;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load-routes
  let shelters intersections with [shelter?]

  ; Debug print to verify shelters
  print (word "Number of shelters: " count shelters)
  ask shelters [ print (word "Shelter at: " xcor ", " ycor " shelter? = " shelter?) ]

  let origins find-origins

  ; Debug print to verify origins
  print (word "Number of origins: " count origins)
  ask origins [
    print (word "Origin at: " xcor ", " ycor)
  ]

  let limit 10
  let limited-origins ifelse-value (count origins > limit) [n-of limit origins] [origins]

  ; Debug print to verify limited origins
  print (word "Number of limited origins: " count limited-origins)
  ask limited-origins [
    print (word "Limited origin at: " xcor ", " ycor)
  ]

  ask limited-origins [
    let goals shelters
    let closest-goal min-one-of goals [distance myself]
    let route Astar self closest-goal goals
    set path route

    ; Debug print for route
    print (word "Route from: " xcor ", " ycor " to " [xcor] of closest-goal ", " [ycor] of closest-goal " path: " route)
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;; LOAD 1/2 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load1
  ca
  setup-init-val
  ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
  set ev_times []
  read-gis-files
  load-network
  load-shelters
  connect-shelters
  reset-timer
  reset-ticks
  set simulation_start_time ticks
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;; LOAD 2/2 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to load2
  load-population
  load-routes
  reset-ticks
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;    GO    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to go
  let current-time (ticks * tick_to_sec / 60)
  if current-time >= max_evacuation_time [
    stop
  ]

  ; Print debug information for residents
  ask residents [
    print (word "Resident " who " at " xcor ", " ycor " reached? " reached? " moving? " moving? " path: " path)
  ]

  ask residents with [reached?] [
    let spd speed
    let dcsn decision
    if dcsn = 1 [
      ask current_int [
        hatch-pedestrians 1 [
          set size 2
          set shape "dot"
          set current_int myself
          set speed spd
          set evacuated? false
          set dead? false
          set moving? false
          set color orange
          set path [path] of myself
          set decision 1
          ifelse is-list? path and empty? path [set shelter -1] [set shelter last path]
          if shelter = -1 and [shelter?] of current_int [set shelter -99]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    if dcsn = 2 [
      ask current_int [
        hatch-cars 1 [
          set size 2
          set current_int myself
          set evacuated? false
          set dead? false
          set moving? false
          set color sky
          set path [path] of myself
          set decision 2
          ifelse is-list? path and empty? path [set shelter -1] [set shelter last path]
          if shelter = -1 and [shelter?] of current_int [set shelter -99]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    die
  ]

  ask pedestrians with [not evacuated? and not dead?] [
    if check-evacuation [mark-evacuated]
  ]

  ask pedestrians with [not moving? and not empty? path and not evacuated? and not dead?] [
    set next_int intersection item 0 path
    set path remove-item 0 path
    set heading towards next_int
    set moving? true
    ask road ([who] of current_int) ([who] of next_int) [set crowd crowd + 1]
  ]

  ask pedestrians with [moving?] [
    ifelse speed > distance next_int [fd distance next_int] [fd speed]
    if (distance next_int < 0.005) [
      set moving? false
      ask road ([who] of current_int) ([who] of next_int) [set crowd crowd - 1]
      set current_int next_int
      if check-evacuation [mark-evacuated]
    ]
  ]

  ask cars with [not evacuated? and not dead?] [
    if check-evacuation [mark-evacuated]
  ]

  ask cars with [not moving? and not empty? path and not evacuated? and not dead?] [
    set next_int intersection item 0 path
    set path remove-item 0 path
    set heading towards next_int
    set moving? true
    ask road ([who] of current_int) ([who] of next_int) [set traffic traffic + 1]
  ]

  ask cars with [moving?] [
    move-gm
    fd speed
    if (distance next_int < 0.005) [
      set moving? false
      ask road ([who] of current_int) ([who] of next_int) [set traffic traffic - 1]
      set current_int next_int
      if check-evacuation [mark-evacuated]
    ]
  ]

  ask residents with [current-time >= max_evacuation_time] [mark-dead]
  ask cars with [current-time >= max_evacuation_time] [mark-dead]
  ask pedestrians with [current-time >= max_evacuation_time] [mark-dead]

  let total-agents count residents + count pedestrians + count cars
  if total-agents > 0 [
    set mortality_rate ((count residents with [dead?] + count pedestrians with [dead?] + count cars with [dead?]) / total-agents) * 100
  ]

  tick
end

Here is a link to my GitHub with the needed files to run the NetLogo model: https://github.com/EmilieAndreasen/Evacuation_model_spatial/tree/main

ERROR: Nothing named RSIG2 has been defined. - could you make the MCVE indeed C-omplete, indeed reproducible? Thanks for taking due care. ( It is this site-policy to post MCVE formulated problems, so please rather follow the rules )

@user3666197 Thanks for the notice, I am very new to using Stackoverflow. I hope I have resolved what you asked for?
